# How to get all values for a key from an array of hashes?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a array of hashes-

```
[{"id"=>1,
  "name"=>"Bose Headphones",
  "created_at"=>"2015-11-25T10:40:29.120Z",
  "updated_at"=>"2015-11-25T10:40:29.120Z",
  "description"=>"Bose",
  "active"=>true},
 {"id"=>3,
  "name"=>"test topic",
  "created_at"=>"2015-11-30T14:34:03.087Z",
  "updated_at"=>"2015-11-30T14:34:03.087Z",
  "description"=>"test",
  "active"=>true},
 {"id"=>4,
  "name"=>"Wireless Mouse",
  "created_at"=>"2015-11-30T14:35:16.583Z",
  "updated_at"=>"2015-11-30T14:35:16.583Z",
  "description"=>"WM",
  "active"=>true},
 {"id"=>5,
  "name"=>"Fit Band",
  "created_at"=>"2015-12-01T04:39:03.034Z",
  "updated_at"=>"2015-12-01T04:39:03.034Z",
  "description"=>"Fitness Band",
  "active"=>true}]
```

I want to get to all the name values in an array and then use `.sample` to get whatever number I want from the list.
The way I am trying is-

```
arr = []
arr = arrOfHash.map{|x| "#{x['name']}"}.sample(1)
```

This is giving me

> Value cannot be an Array when 'multiple' attribute is not present. Not
>   a Array (ArgumentError)

Comment: This will work `arrOfHash.map{|ele| ele['name']}.sample(1)`

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/p9fcNT).

Comment: @PardeepDhingra & Yu ....sorry guys....It works both ways. Some problem with the way the result is getting consumed. Marking all answers correct

Comment: Next time you need to share a complex hash or array of hash, use `require  "pp"` and `pp hash_or_array` to pretty print the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this and it seem to work as expected!

```
arrOfHashes.map{|i| i["name"]}.sample(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the `map` and get the `"name"` from a random hash:

```
arrOfHash.sample['name']
```

Comment: Wow! Simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

There is gem called vine in ruby which lets you access the values based on key.
I would do something like (assuming the above array's  name is array_of_hashes)

```
require 'vine'
name_list = []
array_of_hashes.each do |hash|
   name_list << hash.access("name")
end
puts "All the extracted names from array #{name_list}"
```